# Meteor app works locally but will not load when deployed to meteor.com

Tags: meteor

I have no idea what to do here. Everything was working fine but all of a sudden when I deploy now I get cryptic errors

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helpers' of undefined
bf828391c4c2197419ba1631eee96dfda64d3e0a.js:111 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ServiceConfiguration' of undefined
memrey.meteor.com/:1 Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest http://memrey.meteor.com/app.manifest
memrey.meteor.com/:1 Application Cache Checking event
bf828391c4c2197419ba1631eee96dfda64d3e0a.js:3 Exception in callback of async function: TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined
    at x.setState (http://memrey.meteor.com/bf828391c4c2197419ba1631eee96dfda64d3e0a.js:135:16160)
    at a.contains.o.route.a.extend.onBeforeAction (http://memrey.meteor.com/bf828391c4c2197419ba1631eee96dfda64d3e0a.js:142:3525)
    at p (http://memrey.meteor.com/bf828391c4c2197419ba1631eee96dfda64d3e0a.js:72:4036)
    at http://memrey.meteor.com/bf828391c4c2197419ba1631eee96dfda64d3e0a.js:3:6711
    at C (http://memrey.meteor.com/bf828391c4c2197419ba1631eee96dfda64d3e0a.js:82:4631)
    at p (http://memrey.meteor.com/bf828391c4c2197419ba1631eee96dfda64d3e0a.js:72:4036)
    at http://memrey.meteor.com/bf828391c4c2197419ba1631eee96dfda64d3e0a.js:3:6711
    at b (http://memrey.meteor.com/bf828391c4c2197419ba1631eee96dfda64d3e0a.js:82:4559)
    at p (http://memrey.meteor.com/bf828391c4c2197419ba1631eee96dfda64d3e0a.js:72:4036)
    at http://memrey.meteor.com/bf828391c4c2197419ba1631eee96dfda64d3e0a.js:3:6711
memrey.meteor.com/:1 Application Cache NoUpdate event
bf828391c4c2197419ba1631eee96dfda64d3e0a.js:64 Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() in an onBeforeAction?
```

The code is working just fine locally. So I am lost. I don't even know where to begin debugging.

I am using iron router with useraccounts template package. I am not sure if it is related to that.

Comment: Is code is open source? If yes, can you get a link? I don't know how I can help you if I cant see anything;

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found out what the issue is.

When I defined a template helper like:

`Template.notification.helpers`

I misspelled `notification`

Which caused all the errors. But what is strange is that it worked locally but not when deployed.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions may be tolerated because they are in seperate files when working in development mode, however when deployed in production they're minified and join so the execution of the js file is stopped.

[Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/Xgbh3mmwZjk)